# Features in commercial GIS software missing in FOSS GIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, features

For example, a program I use (TransCAD) has the ability to do travel time matrices based on minimal data input, which is really useful if you're looking at doing back of the envelope type calculations. Another feature it has is the ability to do transit routing and GHG emissions modelling.

What are some of the features you use in non-free/open-source software that you'd like to see implemented in your favorite FOSS GIS software?

Answer (score 6):

- functionality and ease of use of ArcGIS [Network Analyst](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst/index.html) extension
- high quality map production: it's possible with FOSS, but a bunch of extra work
- sophisticated suite of spatial interpolation tools available in OGR/GDAL or another suite with python bindings e.g. Ordinary and tension splines, inverse distance weighted, and kriging