# Fisheye-like projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, czech-republic

I need a special projection for the purpose of effective presentation on a poster. I'd like to present the study area (Czech republic) in a context of whole Europe in such a way, that the Czech republic takes the most area (like 70%) in the center, and the rest of Europe is around it, but ridiculously small. I.e. like massive distortion in favor of the Czech republic, like a fish-eye lens, when you put them close to some object and they will massively magnify it compared to the surroundings.

Is there any projection I can use for this purpose in Quantum GIS? EPSG or the formula in standard (which can be used in QGIS) is welcome.

Comment: Do you NEED the data PROJECTED like this? A graphics solution might be worth considering?

Comment: @Tangnar I was also considering an option to use just graphic program to do this, but it seems more complicated. There would be a huge difference in resolution between Czech rep. and the rest of Europe, so I would either need a really huge image, or the Czech rep would be ugly magnified low res... seems that setting proper projection in QGis could be by far the easiest solution.

Comment: I also think that a graphics software might be the way to go here. Another option would be, instead of a fish-eye lens, to use a fadeout effect. Basically the further you move away from CZ the blurrier/brighter the countries become.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, as it adresses webmapping, but might be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/maps-zoomed-around-specific-locations-magnifying-glass-effect

Comment: You could make this with a [distance or area cartogram](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7406). I am not aware of any QGIS solutions.  You could also make it through a simple custom transformation of the coordinates, if you know how to program such things.  *No* standard projection will create such a map for you, due to the extreme distortions involved.

Comment: Anything in here help (ie. looking for a 'Earth from Space' type of projection)? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78346/ortho-projection-produces-artifacts

Comment: @whuber I hoped I could use some of the standard projections (EPSGs) available in QGIS, but maybe with some reparametrization? Unfortunatelly I don't know with which EPSGs to start and how to reparametrize them.

Comment: This could be done, but you have to be clever about it. By starting in projected coordinates and then unprojecting with a projection that uses a smaller spheroid, you can in effect make a small part of the world seem to be most of a hemisphere. Reprojecting the resulting coordinates with just about any projection suited for that hemisphere would do the trick. What you gain in terms of not having to code any coordinate transformations yourself must be balanced against (a) having to do a lot of trial-and-error experimentation and (b) having minimal control over the distortion around the edges.

Comment: I would use the cartogram route. Simple tools with ready implementation. Just make the value for the Czech rep. much larger than the rest of Europe: scapetoad.choros.ch

Comment: @whuber that would be perfect! But this seem to require expert knowledge. Would you please be so kind to sketch the formula? I would then play and tune the parameters, but I am totally clueless how to do this whole thing.

Comment: If you are not limited by rasters in that map, then the way to go is definitely export to SVG and use Inkspace or other vector graphics editor to make the magnifying glass effect. If you work with vectors, there won't be any ugly pixel issues. +1 for the Czech Republic :)

Comment: Here is a tutorial for CorelDraw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE9hu1g20Gc , in Inkscape you shoul be achieve similar with envelope deformation: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Envelope_Deformation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not fish eye, you can make this style of map as a cartogram.

The benefits of this is that there are ready made tools for the job and will work with a robust set of datasets.

Just make the value for the Czech Republic much larger than the rest of Europe, adjusting the values to suit needs.

A great tool for this is:
[ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vesanto, this is exactly what I needed! :-) Ready-to-use, user-friendly tool! I finally used this. And it pretty looks much like fish-eye to me :-)

Comment: The only thing to note is that it was very very slow, so I had to choose the slowest settings and even lower the number of grid cells manually.. but it looks great. The only thing I regret is that it won't be easy to do this with rasters.

Comment: you can speed things up by using qgis to simplify the geometries, or use a lower resolution shapefile (like the 50m or 110m from Natural Earth)

Answer (score 8):

You might try one of Snyder's `Magnifying Glass` projections found on http://www.csiss.org/map-projections/Azimuthal.html No 32 to 36.

They are based on this publication: https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/70014498

I'm not sure if there is an online resource with the formulas.

Hägerstrand’s Logarithmic Map might also fit your needs: http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/projects/tobler/Projections/sld105.htm

Or a square root azimuthal projection: http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/projects/tobler/Projections/sld109.htm

References can be found in http://www.cartoperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/download/cp59-tobler/307 and in "Small-Scale Map Projection Design" by Frank Canters (available from Google books).

Comment: Thanks Andrej! That all looks very interesting! But without the formulas or epsgs or any other easy way how to use them I will not be able to use it :-(

Comment: There will be no EPSG code (no oil searching will be made with those maps!), but you can look out for the publications.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pseudo-fisheye done in Postgres/Postgis.
I used QChainage plugin to create 1000 points along each country border.
The points were reprojected around null island (0,0) using the logarithm of distance, but with azimuth preserved.

[image]

I used Plat Caree to make it circular, as wgs84 gives a more ellipsoid appearance.

```
select
    st_asewkt(
        st_endpoint(
            st_scale(
                st_rotate(
                    st_makeline(
                        st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),4326),
                        st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,1),4326)
                    ),
                    st_azimuth(
                        st_setsrid(
                            st_makepoint(0,0),
                            4326
                        )
                        ,
                        ST_translate(geom,-15.0,-50.0)
                    ) 
                ),
                -(1.0+(7.0*log(ST_Distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),4326),ST_translate(geom,-15.0,-50.0))))),
                (1.0+(7.0*log(ST_Distance(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),4326),ST_translate(geom,-15.0,-50.0)))))

            )   
        )
    ) as pt

from
    qqq3lines
```

Comment: interesting, thanks Steven! Can it be made more so that the Czech Rep is even bigger compared to the rest?

Comment: @tomas yes... you need to tweak the constants I used in the st_scale().. try increasing the 1.0 to 2.0, and decreasing the 7.0 to something smaller.

Answer (score 1):

[D3](http://d3js.org/) has a [fisheye distortion plugin](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/), which I found by Googling "svg fisheye transform".. It might be useful for your situation. Basically, I'm suggesting [converting some of your shapefiles to SVG (or GeoJSON?)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39277/how-to-create-a-geojson-that-works-with-d3) making your map using the increasingly popular D3.js library.

My thinking was, I knew the country boundary geometries could be converted to SVG vector types, and I suspected that as SVG, there might be more suitable approaches to implement the fisheye transform you're desiring.

I agree with the other commenters that illustration/graphic software is more appropriate to your scenario, and since D3 works with some common data formats (SVG and GeoJSON), it may provide a solution for you.

Comment: thanks, but isn't D3 a library for programmers, for web creators? I possibly need a program that will create a single picture for me, possibly without a need of programming.

Comment: @Tomas, fair enough. Since your question is simply titled "Fisheye-like projection", though, it's going to have a strong search ranking in google for similar queries, which over time will likely include some developers. Eventually this answer might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need an extreme distortion for the Czech Republic to look like that. There is a fairly popular photographic "stereographic projection" technique sometimes used in panorama photography to create "globe worlds" which may work if you used the result as overlay over Europe. (Do not consider this an answer as this is purely hypothetical and I've never tried it with a map) Also, this would be more of a graphics/photo editing project because you would probably have to photograph your printed map or possibly export it out of GIS to a high resolution image then then copy and crop a series of images around a central point (centered on a uniform area in the middle with sufficient overlap) so that they can be used as input into the panorama function. Once you have the "stereographic projection" image created you could then overlay over a map of Europe.

Of course you would need to add labels after the fact in Illustrator, Corel Draw or by importing the final image as raster back into GIS and creating some graphics/ annotations.

Google "stereographic projection panorama" to see examples.

Here is an example tutorial: http://www.photographymad.com/pages/view/little-planet-photos-5-simple-steps-to-making-panorama-worlds

[image]